# Create large nxn co-occurrence matrix in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, insert

I am creating a 12,000 x 12,000 co-occurrence matrix for which I have around 5 million values to be inserted. My first pandas dataframe consists of the 5 million word pairs and the number of times the pair occurred:

Dataframe **count_data**:

**word_A | word_B | count**

Furthermore, I have a zero-filled 12,000 x 12,000 co-occurrence matrix as a pandas dataframe, called **co_matrix**. The row- and column names correspond with all the words from the word pairs. Now, I am looking for a fast way to insert all the co-occurrence counts from the first dataframe to the right 2 (!) positions in the co-occurrence dataframe. My code, that takes way too much time, is as follows:

```
for i in range(len(count_data)):
    co_matrix.loc[count_data['word_A'][i],count_data['word_B'][i]] = co_matrix.loc[count_data['word_B'][i],count_data['word_A'][i]] = count_data['count'][i]
```

The double assignment ensures the symmetry of the co-occurrence matrix. How can I insert the 5 million values in the matrix in a faster way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not very familiar with pandas but couldn't you use different threads? Then every thread could do the initialization for x columns. x depending on the number of cpu's you've got.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, not very familiar with parallelizing yet. In case of 4 CPU's, this would reduce running time by factor 4 or somewhat more I guess? I have the feeling that smarter coding could solve this issue..

Comment: yes, about factor 4, probably a little bit less.